# Removing offensiveness from swear word

Tags: word-choice, politeness, offensive-language, minced-oaths

Is there a consensus in terms of the ranking of offensiveness given by the word "damn" and its derivatives?

- Damn
- Darn
- Dang
- Ding (as in ding-busted)

I assume that the less a word sounds like the original swear word, the more polite it is considered. I was wondering, depending on the audience, as long as it's not "damn" does it matter what substitute word is used? For example could it be considered offensive to say "darn" instead of "dang"?

Comment: To most, 1 darn (of a sock) leads to an inordinate number of damns.

Comment: I believe 'ding' and 'dang' (here) are the same word, just spelled with a different vowel to reflect regional pronunciation differences.  We were asked by a waitress taking our order in a rural coastal  seafood restaurant in South Carolina, *Kang or kwayne?* That is, what size platters would we like, *king or queen?*

Comment: Asking if something *could* be *considered* offensive may be primarily opinion based. A better question would be "In what context might it be considered offensive?" That would actually have an answer. Also, please, one authoritatively answerable question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically only 'damn' is a real swearword in the list your give. All of the others are 'minced oaths', i.e. "euphemistic expressions replacing the offensive part of speech with something else".

The problem with a minced oath is that it loses its euphemistic value if everybody knows what it means, to the point where it becomes (to some people) the same as the offensive version.

In short the further what you say is from the original, and the less well-known it is, the less likely it is to be offensive. "Darn" is well known, and might offend. The others are further away. If you want to be completely sure of not offending, don't use 'filler' words like that at all - replace them with words that have actual meaning.

Comment: There are also contexts where 'damn' is not a swear word at all, as in "The prophet damned the false idols and cast them down."

Comment: Also - and just to address one small part of the question body - there is no consensus on how relatively offensive particular words might be.